# Access bash special variable from makefile

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-make

I am running:

```
» make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

This works, from `bash`:

```
$ echo $RANDOM
14522
```

This does not work:

```
$ make echo-random
```

With `Makefile`:

```
echo-random:
        echo $(RANDOM)
```

Some questions:

- Does `make` use a shell to run commands?
- Is it possible to tell shell to use `bash`?
- Can `make` somehow access `bash` special env variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke `bash` with the `-c` argument (that tells it the next argument is a command it has to run and exit):

```
echo-random:
    @bash -c 'echo $$RANDOM'
```

This way, each invocation of `make echo-random` starts a new `bash` instance that runs the command `echo $RANDOM` and it produces the outcome you expect.

Comment: This works indeed. It seems that make runs `/bin/sh` by default, unless we set the `SHELL` var **in** the makefile (since it is not inherited)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @axiac is good. This is an alternative:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash

random := $(shell echo $$RANDOM)

echo-random:
    echo $$RANDOM
    echo $(random)
```

Output:

```
» make
echo $RANDOM
18826
echo 16300
16300
```

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#Choosing-the-Shell) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html)